# Save dynamic html form data to table (Laravel 5.2)

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have created a dynamic form for making an offer and i don't know how to solve the problem saving that data to a database. I'm using Laravel 5.2 and now i need to make a model and controller....can someone help me please?

How to save this into a database table?

I'm open for hints and tips too, maybe it could be done somehow differently?

[This is live form](http://mein-informatiker.de/public/angebot)
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wwv6g0ku/)

```
<div>
<h1>Angebot</h1>
<form method="POST" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<table id="t1">
    <tr>
        <th><button type="button" class="addRow">Personal hinzuf&uuml;gen</button></th>
        <th>Anzahl</th>
        <th>Preis pro Stunde</th>
        <th>Stunden</th>
        <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row0" class="item">
        <td><select name="personal" class="select"><optgroup label="Personal">
            <option selected="true" disabled="true" style="display:none">--ausw&auml;hlen</option>
            <option value="koeche">K&ouml;che</option>
            <option value="barkeeper">Barkeeper</option>
            <option value="garderobiere">Garderobiere</option>
            <option value="chauffeure">Chauffeure</option>
            <option value="oberkellner">Oberkellner</option>
            <option value="serviceleitung">Serviceleitung</option>
            <option value="hilfskoch">Hilfskoch</option>
            <option value="servicekraefte">Servicekr&auml;fte</option>
            </optgroup>
            </select></td>
        <td><input name="anzahl" class="qnty amount" value="" type="number" min="0" step="1"/></td>
        <td><input name="preisps" class="price amount" value="" /></td>
        <td><input name="stunden" class="hours amount" value="" /></td>
        <td><input name="total" class="total" value="" readonly="readonly" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<br />

<table id="t2">
  <tr>
    <th>Netto =<br></th>
    <th><input id="netto" readonly="readonly" name="netto" type="text" value=""></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Steuer 19% =<br></td>
    <td><input id="steuer" readonly="readonly" name="steuer" type="text" value=""></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Brutto =<br></td>
    <td><input id="brutto" readonly="readonly" name="brutto" type="text" value=""></td>
  </tr>
</table>
    <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  <input type="reset" value="Reset">
  </form>
</div>
```

and here is the javascript code

```
// main function when page is opened
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // function for adding a new row
        var r = 0;
        if(r<11){
            $('.addRow').click(function () {
                r++;
                $('#t1').append('<tr id="row' + r + '" class="item"><td><select name="personal' + r + '" class="select"><optgroup label="Personal"><option selected="true" disabled="true" style="display:none">--ausw&auml;hlen</option><option value="koeche">K&ouml;che</option><option value="barkeeper">Barkeeper</option><option value="garderobiere">Garderobiere</option><option value="chauffeure">Chauffeure</option><option value="oberkellner">Oberkellner</option><option value="serviceleitung">Serviceleitung</option><option value="hilfskoch">Hilfskoch</option><option value="servicekraefte">Servicekr&auml;fte</option></optgroup></select></td><td><input name="anzahl' + r + '" class="qnty amount" value="" type="number" min="0" step="1"/></td><td><input name="preisps' + r + '" class="price amount" value="" /></td><td><input name="stunden' + r + '" class="hours amount" value="" /></td><td><input name="total' + r + '" class="total" value="" readonly="readonly" /></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="' + r + '" class="btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');
            });
            // remove row when X is clicked
            $(document).on("click", ".btn_remove", function () {
                var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
                $("#row" + button_id + '').remove();
            });

            // calculate everything
            $(document).on("keyup", ".amount", calcAll);
        }
    });

    // function for calculating everything
    function calcAll(event) {
        // calculate total for one row
          $(".item").each(function () {
            var qnty = 1;
            var price = 1;
            var hours = 1;
            var total = 1;
            if (!isNaN(parseFloat($(this).find(".qnty").val()))) {
                qnty = parseFloat($(this).find(".qnty").val());
            }
            if (!isNaN(parseFloat($(this).find(".price").val()))) {
                price = parseFloat($(this).find(".price").val());
            }
            if (!isNaN(parseFloat($(this).find(".hours").val()))) {
                hours = parseFloat($(this).find(".hours").val());
            }
            total = qnty * price * hours;
            $(this).find(".total").val(total.toFixed(2));
        });


        // sum all totals
        var sum = 0;
        $(".total").each(function () {
            if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
                sum += parseFloat(this.value);
            }
        });

        // show values in netto, steuer, brutto fields
        $("#netto").val(sum.toFixed(2));
        $("#steuer").val(parseFloat(sum * 0.19).toFixed(2));
        $("#brutto").val(parseFloat(sum + parseFloat(($("#steuer").val()))).toFixed(2));

    }

    // replace , with . and block writing letters
    $.fn.ForceNumericOnly = function() {
            return this.each(function() {
          if($(this).data('forceNumericOnly')){ return; }
          $(this).data('forceNumericOnly', true);
                $(this).keydown(function(e) {
                    if(e.keyCode==188 || e.keyCode==110 || e.keyCode==108){
                        e.preventDefault(); 
                        $(this).val($(this).val() + '.');
                    }
                        var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode || 0;
                        return (key == 8 || key == 9 || key == 46 || key == 110 || key == 188 || key == 190 || (key >= 35 && key <= 40) || (key >= 48 && key <= 57) || (key >= 96 && key <= 105));                
                });
            });
    };
    // execute function on element focus
    $(document).on('focus', '.amount', function(){
        $(this).ForceNumericOnly();
    });
```

Comment: The question is still not answered....i hope someone with more experience with laravel will read this question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question

1) you added "r" variable for rows limit in wrong place so add like below

```
 var r = 1; 
 $('.addRow').click(function () {
  if(r<10)
       {  
        r++;
        $('#t1').append('<tr id="row' + r + '" class="item"><td><select name="personal' + r + '" class="select"><optgroup label="Personal"><option selected="true" disabled="true" style="display:none">--ausw&auml;hlen</option><option value="koeche">K&ouml;che</option><option value="barkeeper">Barkeeper</option><option value="garderobiere">Garderobiere</option><option value="chauffeure">Chauffeure</option><option value="oberkellner">Oberkellner</option><option value="serviceleitung">Serviceleitung</option><option value="hilfskoch">Hilfskoch</option><option value="servicekraefte">Servicekr&auml;fte</option></optgroup></select></td><td><input name="anzahl' + r + '" class="qnty amount" value="" type="number" min="0" step="1"/></td><td><input name="preisps' + r + '" class="price amount" value="" /></td><td><input name="stunden' + r + '" class="hours amount" value="" /></td><td><input name="total' + r + '" class="total" value="" readonly="readonly" /></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="' + r + '" class="btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');
        }
    });

    // remove row when X is clicked
    $(document).on("click", ".btn_remove", function () {
        r--;
        var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
            $("#row" + button_id + '').remove();
        });
```

after above change you will add only 10 row in the table.

2) Question you need to create one json from the created table structure and pass that json in the server side through ajax and in server side parsing your json and store that information in the database.

And from the table design look like it will be 2 table one table have master information and another detail table which have detail information.

Please let me know if you need sample code for that.

Comment: Thank you so much.....it works as it should now! Do you know how to save this to a database table?

Comment: For that you need to create json from the created dynamic table and pass that json in server side and deserialize your json and store information in the database.

Comment: But what if i'm using Laravel? Maybe there are some automated functions for doing that? And the problem is i don't even know how this table should look like? What to put for column names?

Comment: sorry for that I don't have idea about that.

Comment: Maybe someone knows how to make this better? Different? I'm open for any advice!